# ES6 Module directory structure

Tags: javascript

I didn't find anything on Google but I'm wondering if there's a "best practise" of structuring an ES6 project in terms of directories and module exports.

Currently I do have two different ways in mind:

Using an `index.js` for every module and export everything:

```
app.js
modules/
  ModuleName/
    ModuleFile.js
    index.js
```

`ModuleFile.js` would look something like `export class ModuleFile { }`, the `index.js` would be simply

```
export * from 'ModuleFile'
```

This makes it possible to import files with `import {ModuleFile} from 'modules/ModuleName'`. Readable, but requires an `index.js` for every module, even if the module has just one single file.

Second approach would be without using `index.js` files, but that would mean import statements would become slightly redundant `import {ModuleFile} from 'modules/ModuleName/ModuleFile'`.

Are there any best practises on this topic?

Comment: What is "moduleFile" supposed to mean? If there's just a single file, either put it as `moduleName/index.js` or just as `moduleName.js` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach seems fine, I don't see a problem with it. In two different projects I've worked (different companies) it was the pattern used.

You could also put the ModuleFile.js content directly in index.js:

```
app.js
modules/
  ModuleName/
    index.js
```

Or create a file directly for a module:

```
app.js
modules/
    moduleName.js
```

In cases only a "file" is necessary. The evident problem is that changes or the growth of the module may force this structure to change. There would also be an inconsistence in terms of structure with other modules.

Comment: For now I went with the "putting content into the `index.js` in case it's just one file". Works fine, but still curious if there are any other ways to solve this. (I'll mark this as answer later this day, thanks)